# send a word device to device on wifi direct android using a service

Tags: wifi

We required to send a word from one mobile device to another using wifi-direct. The wifi-direct, wifi-discoveryservice samples given in android sdk shows its usage with MainActivity. As we have app with multiple activities and from selected activities we need to send particular word to another device on wifi, we are looking for a simple 'SendWordWiFiService' approach.

Any related input in this regard is awaited. We are struggling for last 1 week trying to implement wifi-direct, wifi-discoveryservice in a project having multiple activities. But no success.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Sockets. If you haven't done them before, I suggest reading [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) as it got me started. Additionally you might find [Oracle's documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) to be useful. In particular, you may want to read up on of using threads to run server sockets.

The steps you need to take are:

1. Discover peers using Wi-Fi Direct
2. Make a peer connection between decies (NB: Be mindful of who the group owner is once this is done, if you're application needs to differentiate between a group owner and a group client(s)).
3. Once the peer connection is made, sockets can be set up between the peers for the transfer of data streams, ie sending words in your case. You might find it most logical to set your Wi-Fi Direct GroupOwner as the server socket, and your GroupClient devices as a client which connects to the server.

I hope that helps.